# PHP - What are these and how do I echo certain values?

Tags: php, variables, web

I'm looking to create a basic IP tracker, I'm trying to figure out how to echo certain aspects of this variable, cheers:

```
{"ip":"MY IP","country_code":"GB","country_name":"United Kingdom","region_code":"ENG","region_name":"England","city":"MY CITY","zip_code":"MY CODE","time_zone":"Europe/London","latitude":----,"longitude":-----,"metro_code":-}
```

This is the code which I was reading up on:

```
$location = file_get_contents('http://freegeoip.net/json/'.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
print_r($location);

{
  "ip": "77.99.179.98",
  "country_code": "GB",
  "country_name": "United Kingdom",
  "region_code": "H9",
  "region_name": "London, City of",
  "city": "London",
  "zipcode": "",
  "latitude": 51.5142,
  "longitude": -0.0931,
  "metro_code": "",
  "areacode": ""
```

}

Cheers!

Comment: It's `JSON`. use `json_decode` to convert it into an object and use accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

To echo something do

```
//Example
      $locationObject = json_decode($location);
      echo $locationObject->ip; 
//Prints out: 77.99.179.98
```

More info 
http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/php-js/json/decode.php

Comment: Thanks! You've solved my problem.

Comment: Glad to help! Google a bit about JSON it's great to have some knowledge about it :)